# Deploying recommendation model from Tensorflow/models after training?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, recommendation-engine, tensorflow-model-garden

I followed the small tutorial here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/recommendation
to train a recommendation model based on the ml-1m movielens dataset. How would I go about deploying this to start using it?

I've tried adding my own code to convert the keras model into tflite to put on firebase, but converter.convert() throws a value error. I've looked into Tensorflow serving, but the checkpoint that it outputs does not follow the format needed from what it appears. I'm not even sure how to format the input data to get recommendations.

I am new to ml and tensorflow, so I appreciate details. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The [content recommendation codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/contentrecommendation-android) from [Firebase ML codelabs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml/codelabs) has detailed steps on how to train, convert, and deploy a TFLite recommendations model to a mobile app.